# Add image to lock screen C#

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, canvas, isolatedstorage

What i am trying to achieve is my canvas to be saved as image in isolated storage and that image then be used as lock screen.
The problem is that it happens only once,after that when the canvas is updated and when i try changing the lock screen with new image, it is not updated. I tried the following code :

```
Uri uri;
    async private void LockScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bitmap = null;
        bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)bgCanvas.Width, (int)bgCanvas.Height);
        bitmap.Render(bgCanvas,null);
        bitmap.Invalidate();

        using(IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            //Delete old background file from isolated storage
            if (iso.FileExists("Background"))
            {
                iso.DeleteFile("Background");
            }
            //Save canvas to isolated storage 
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isostream = iso.CreateFile("Background"))
            {
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(bitmap, isostream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                //isostream.Close();
            }            
        }
        //Access isolated storage file and put as lock screen
        try
        {
            var isProvider = Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication;  
            if (!isProvider)
            {
                var permission = await Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();
                isProvider = permission == Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenRequestResult.Granted;
            }
            if (isProvider)
            {
                uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/Background", UriKind.Absolute);
                Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);
                MessageBox.Show("Lock Screen updated!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't update the lockscreen picture.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured while updating the lockscreen picture: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

The message box shows that lock screen is updated even though it is not.
I think the file isn't updated in the isolated storage but cant figure out why ?

Comment: You are creating a new folder called "Background" and pictures are inside that folder right? While saving, can you get the picture first?

Comment: No there is no folder created.I am creating just one file named background and replacing it every time. But apparently it isn't updated after the first time i.e. when it is created.

Comment: Its okay, i got the solution. Actually somehow due to the same name of file, the file wasnt overwritten, so now i give a new name evrytym to the new and delete all d previous files.